# Trying to install mysql on mac osx 10.6 but i get an error that i need to upgrade. The issue is that version 5.5 doesn't work on osx 10.6

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, osx-snow-leopard

I use mac osx 10.6. I already had phpmyadmin installed. I then proceeded to install mysql version 5.1. That mysql version was recommended for osx 10.6. Everything worked fine until i typed my password into phpmyadmin and i get this error that says i should upgrade mysql server to 5.5. 
I then proceed to install mysql 5.5, but everytime i tried to open mysql it would crash. My "system preferences" would crash. On top of that phpmyadmin wouldn't let me log in. And the command "mysql -v" would tell me that i was doing something unauthorized. 
So i decided to remove everything through terminal and re-installed mysql version 5.1. But i still get the error that the version is outdated. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This question is hard to follow, please edit to add detail. What do you mean by "mysql -v would tell me that I was doing something illegal"? What was the response of that command?

Comment: I removed that version of mysql so i can't remember exactly that command said. Something along the lines of not being authorized to perform that action.

Comment: Are you sure you can't update from 10.6? That's a severely dated version from 2009 that likely won't see any support for current or future versions of MySQL. Most modern OS X builds assume 64-bit only, as has been the case since 10.8. If it's possible, update to 10.8.

Comment: I could, but it means i'd have to backup everything and re-install laravel (which was an extreme pain). This is a 64-bit btw.

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I am using version 4.5

Comment: On https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ we indicate that phpMyAdmin 4.5.0 requires MySQL 5.5. Try to install phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.11 instead; this will work with your (old) MySQL 5.1.